# Adjust height of bootstrap button automatically according to other bootstrap buttons

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

First of all I want to center a glyphicon vertically and horizontally inside a button. So far I tried it with the CSS attributes `position: relative;` and `position: absolute;`, see [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/QPdb9YPWUc) but it won't work.

Secondly when I resizing the window the button can become the height of two text lines, because of the `white-space: normal;` attribute.
How can I achieve, that in this case the glyphicon button will update his height and the glyphicon is still centered (horizontally and vertically).

[image: ![normal button height]
[image: double height of right button]

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="fullscreenButton">
        <span id="fullscreenButtonGlyphicon" class="glyphicon glyphicon-fullscreen gylphiconInsideButton"></span>
      </button>  
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5"> 
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" id="showAllGpsMarker">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></span>&nbsp;long long long long long long long long long long long text
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>    
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#showAllGpsMarker{
    white-space: normal;
}

#fullscreenButton {
    width:100%;
    position: relative;
}
#fullscreenButtonGlyphicon{
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all remove all your `position:absolute/relative`. After removing it will already look neat, then you want the left button to take full width of `col-md-2`so you give it `width 100%`. You should also use `col-sm` and `col-xs` rules for smaller devices. This will fix the left button.

Now you want the left button to take the same height as the right button on smaller devices, for this I used `media queries` and gave it a `padding: 16px 0;`

Depending on where you want to have your breakpoint you should adjust the media query with the needed `px`

See updated [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/V8uiCE2k8K)

Hope this helps a bit.

Comment: Centering the glyphicon works, but I am still able to produce different heights of the two buttons, like the second picture in my question.

Comment: You have to use media queries for this, thats easy, I can do it for you, but you should understand it.

Comment: I understand the technique, but is it right, that I have to calculate the exactly value when the linebreak happens?

Comment: Thats how media queries work, its probably not the best solution but it will work for sure. And you can continue to work.